# Window Redirect Confusion

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a JavaScript function to redirect the window to different webpage with this command:

```
window.location.replace("/EluLander/doctor/doctordash.html");
```

This is the url of the webpage when I open it manually:

```
file:///C:/Users/Elijah%20Spiegel/Desktop/EluLander/doctor/doctordash.html
```

And the url of the page I am redirecting FROM is this:

```
file:///C:/Users/Elijah%20Spiegel/Desktop/EluLander/Landingpage.html
```

When I run the function, it leads me to

```
file:///C:/EluLander/doctor/doctordash.html
```

What am I goofing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace is functioning exactly as it should. Since you are not using a webserver, `file:///C:/` is acting as the host.

To get the redirect to work properly, change your code to:

```
window.location.replace("/Users/Elijah%20Spiegel/Desktop/EluLander/doctor/doctordash.html")
```